# Any answer to a question automatically upvotes said question - FEATURE-REQUEST

Tags: feature-request, answers, up-votes

I find it contradictory to the concept of upvoting that someone finds a question worthy of an answer, yet unworthy of an upvote.

I get the impression that it is a bit egotistical to not even care to upvote.  I also get the impression that these are point seekers, who care little about evaluating and awarding credit where credit is due.

As a longtime SO user, I believe that it would be only fair to award 1 upvote per answer (and deter the answerer from downvoting the question, naturally).

Comment: That sounds like a fundamental change to the underlying code. Nothing that we can do about that.

Comment: In what way is that a fundamental change? Not to the code, surely? `if (question_is_answered) UpVoteQuestion();` However it might cause unexpected consequences.

Comment: This feature is not specific to this particular branch of Stackexchange but to the whole network. A change to that mechanism is very unlikely to be implemented on this stack only. The question therefore needs to be taken to Meta.Stackexchange, like Nick's answer suggests.

Comment: The upvote button tooltip has "The question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". Usually it is easy to answer a question without research effort. It only takes the research effort.

Comment: that is for OTHERS.  anyone who answers a question automatically deems it answer-worthy, therfore upvatable.  Otherwise one might argue that the answerer is only after points...

Answer (score 2):

You raise an interesting point, although the concept would probably belong to every part of the Stack Exchange network, and thus might be better put at https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

You *might* argue that someone might answer a bad question, so upvoting a question just because it gets an answer might skew the results a bit. In fact, if every question is automatically upvoted by an answer it might conceivably push people to not answer, or answer in a comment, which could change existing behaviour.

Comment: one might argue so.  but a bad question does not deserve answering if it cannot be fixed.  if it CAN be fixed, then it becomes a good question and deserving of answer(s).

Comment: @tonygil Hmm... I have seen bad questions that have shown little work on the askers part, which I *have* then answered (perhaps wrongly), maybe because I felt sorry for them or to get them on their way or it was a commonly asked question (but couldn't find the duplicate), but didn't feel that the question was worth upvoting (for a range of reasons: obvious answer, little forethought on their part, poorly worded/presented etc.)

Comment: but, in general, that is not the case

Answer (score 2):

It bothers me too that there aren't enough upvotes on Arduino SE. I am yet to come up with a good solution.

As well as upvotes, bronze badges (eg. Student) are used to encourage good questions.

One thing that doesn't work in our favour is that we have so many new users every day who ask their question, get an answer and then never stick around to pay it forward. And because they are in and out they don't read/learn the guides that SE is founded on, resulting often in poor questions. The users who do stick around are great.

To answer your question, I'm not sure if your proposal is the silver bullet to get more upvotes happening. Perhaps it is something Stack overflow could test and evaluate. Like others I suggest you post the idea on [Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/.).

However, we all could put more effort into upvoting (me included). It was other people upvoting [my first answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/21978/19409) that inspired me to come back to the community and contribute more.